# Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure already exist but cannot find reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have cloned a project from repository, After resolving other references issues I am stuck at

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

the Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' is already installed but I can not find its reference and neither I can uninstall this package

**Update**
I have accidentally removed that reference and now I cannot find that reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure is not in your GAC.

Add this reference `(Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure)` to your project as the following.

- Right click the reference.
- Go to properties.
- Set copy to local to true.

Comment: I have accidentally deleted this reference but now I cannot find this reference in list

Comment: Add it again by right click the reference -> add reference ->  on search type referece name (Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure) select the reference -> click OK

Comment: I cloned repo again and follow your instructions but I am still facing the same issue

Comment: I tried to help you, Hope you find the solution asap :).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created an other ASP.NET MVC empty project and copy

> Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll

file to the bin folder of this project and it worked for me